# Is it natural to say someone excels in his class?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, sentence-request, alternatives

If Tom is a top student in his class, can I say 'Tom excels in his class'? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is not very idiomatic and natural to say. I'd prefer:

> Tom excels in his studies

Or if you want to mention the class you can go for the classic:

> Tom was the top in his class